# additional suffix not supported. How to get the same result without using additional suffix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using

```
split -b 100KB -d "${FEED_FILE_NAME2}" project_attributes_${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}_" --additional-suffix=".dat"
```

can i achieve the same result without using additional prefix as its not supported ? If not then by using any other command?

Comment: You could, after splitting, loop over the files and rename them, but I wonder why your _split_ does not have this option. What does `split --version` say?

Comment: Don't you see an error in your quoting? Even the stackoverflow coloring is helpful.

Comment: @user1934428 its running fine in local, the testing environment does not support —additional suffix.  I could rename the files but is it possible to rename the extension too? Because using additional suffix the extension becomes .txtaa and so on

Comment: Extension is part of the file name, but I was asking of course what platform the script is running. If the testing environment is not Linux, what OS does it have?

Comment: @user1934428 its Linux. i think the testers are using outdated version and thats why support for additional suffix is not there. Can it be done using awk command, splitting files based on size?

Comment: That's why I suggested to output the version of the split command!

Comment: @AnuragPandey : If your program is running on a real antique system, I would first check what you have available there at all, and in what versions (maybe the bash is still version 1???). Of course you can write your own program doing the task - in Perl, awk, even in bash -, but in any case you need to know what version you can use, otherwise you are running into the same problem.

Comment: @user1934428 GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)<br>Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software

Comment: And the version of the `split` command on that platform?